# How can one declare a function using a function type in GO

Tags: syntax, go

Suppose you declare a function type

```
type mapFunc func(value int) int
```

Can you declare a function by using this type without duplicating it? Something like:

```
doubleIt := mapFunc {
    return 2*value
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know, the shortest way is still:

```
doubleIt := func (value int) int {
    return value * 2
}
```

So it's not getting any shorter, and I don't think it would be more readable to decouple the function signature from its body. The benefit of declaring a named func type is using it in other declarations.

No extra conversions like `doubleId := mapFunc(func...)` needed, because of the [type identity](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_identity) rules:

> Two function types are identical if they have the same number of parameters and result values, corresponding parameter and result types are identical, and either both functions are variadic or neither is. Parameter and result names are not required to match.

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can `func` is a [first-class](https://golang.org/doc/codewalk/functions/) type like any other pre-declared types, although it doesn't make much sense to declare it this way:

```
package main

import "fmt"

// You need not a named argument for a named type
type mapFunc func(int) int

func main() {
        doubleIt := mapFunc(func(value int) int { return value * 2})
        fmt.Println(doubleIt(2))      // 4
}
```

This is to illustrate that function is just another type in Go and can be treated like any other named type.

Comment: Wrapping with `mapFunc` is redundant due to the [type identity](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_identity) rules.

Comment: Well @rfalke was asking in the context when he declared a function as named type. He might have had specific use. This is not common but simply to illustrate his point.